# KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a new learn in pandas and trying to count the number of products bought by a user with two excel:

1.customer id(selected customer id to be used)

2.transaction record (all the transactions),like:

```
|cusid|products|
-----------------------
|    1      | 12,13,14|    
|    1      | 05,12,12|
```

some of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import turicreate as tc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import sys
sys.path.append("..")

customers=pd.read_csv('testdata/data/recommend_1.csv')
transactions=pd.read_csv('testdata/data/trx_data.csv')
print(list(customers))
print (list(transactions))
print(customers.shape)
customers.head()
print(transactions.shape)
transactions.head()

data=pd.melt(transactions.set_index('cusid')['products'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True),id_vars=['cusid'],value_name='products')\
        .dropna().drop(['variable'],axis=1)\
        .groupby(['cusid','products'])\
        .agg({'products':'count'})\
        .rename(columns={'products':'purchase_count'})\
        .reset_index(drop=True)\
        .rename(columns={'products':'productId'})

data['productId']=data['productId'].astype(np.int64)        
print(list(data))
print(data.shape)
data.head()
```

Results as following:

```
['cusid']
['cusid', 'products']
(1000, 1)
(62483, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recomm.py", line 20, in <module>
    data=pd.melt(transactions.set_index('cusid')['products'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True),id_vars=['cusid'],value_name='products')\
  File "/Users/bijing/anaconda2/envs/turi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py", line 48, in melt
    "".format(missing=list(missing)))
KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['cusid']"
```

Comment: Can you check whether you have whitespaces in your column names?

Comment: do not have, I just copy my code here.

Comment: @PoppyBee can you check the same in your raading CSV file?

Comment: have checked, and do not have any space

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you share the `transactions.head()` output, seems the second column is a string. So you need to split and flatten it. After this the logic is very simple as following:

```
customers = pd.read_csv('testdata/data/recommend_1.csv')
transactions = pd.read_csv('testdata/data/trx_data.csv')
transactions['products'] = transactions['products'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))
transactions = transactions['products'].apply(pd.Series).merge(transactions, right_index=True, left_index=True).drop(['products'], axis=1).melt(id_vars = ['cusid'], value_name='product').drop('variable', axis=1).dropna()
whitelist = set(customers['cusid'].tolist())
res = transactions[transactions['cusid'].isin(whitelist)].groupby(['cusid', 'product']).size().rename('count').reset_index()
```

Comment: the output of transactions.head()   <br/>cusid products<br/>
0 0 20<br/>
1 0 216|52|260|93|93|93<br/>
2 0 69|69<br/>
3 0 1|1|31|31<br/>
4 0 260|256<br/>got other error：<br/>`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recomm.py", line 28, in <module>
    data['productId']=data['productId'].astype(np.int64)        
  
KeyError: 'productId'
`

Answer (score 7):

Try to run `data = data.reset_index()` before you run the melting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the names of column were `[2016,2017,2018,2019]` which are integer and I converted the type by:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

The columns names: `['2016','2017','2018','2019']` and the problem is solved.